# Turning a string of names into a name with initials and last name

Tags: ruby, string

I need to do the following with Ruby:

> Turn this string of names `"joseph jeremiah bloggs"` into `"J.J.Bloggs"`

It has to work for any number of names with the last name always the full word and the other names initials.

I have the following code so far:

```
def initials(name)
  name.split.map(&:capitalize).join('.')
end
```

Which returns `"Joseph.Jeremiah.Bloggs"`

Is there a way to get the initials for the first two words?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one way that follows your code:

```
def initials(name)
  *rest, last = name.split
  (rest.map{|e| e[0]} << last).map(&:capitalize).join('.')
end
```

Using the splat `*` makes `rest` collect all the names except the last.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
"joseph jeremiah bloggs"
.gsub(/\w+\s*/){|s| ($'.empty? ? s : "#{s[0]}.").capitalize}                    #'
# => "J.J.Bloggs"
```

or

```
"joseph jeremiah bloggs"
.gsub(/\w+\s+/){|s| "#{s[0].upcase}."}.sub(/\w+\z/, &:capitalize)
# => "J.J.Bloggs"
```

Comment: This works, but I am not far along enough in my Ruby training to understand all of it. Would you mind explaining it through? Thank you so much

Comment: The first one does a regex match for both the non-last and the last parts, and then conditions the replacement depending on that. The second one first replaces the non-last parts, then replaces the last part.

Comment: That looks more like a `Perl` solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated Solution (even though this thread is closed I still want to help others). I feel like this solution is easier for newer Ruby developers to understand.

```
def initialize_name(name)
  name = name.split(" ")
  name.map {|n| n.equal?(name.last) ? n.capitalize : n[0].capitalize }.join(". ")
end

initialize_name "joseph jeremiah blogg" # => J. J. Blogg
```

#### Old Solution

This is what I came up with. Not the prettiest but it works, I am going to try and make this look nicer for you though.

```
joe = "joseph jeremiah blogg"

def initialize_name(name)
  return_value = ""
  name = name.split(" ")
  name.each do |n|
    if n.equal? name.last
      return_value << "#{n.capitalize}"
    else
      return_value << "#{n[0].capitalize}. "
    end
  end
  return_value
end

puts initialize_name joe # => "J. J. Blogg"
```

Comment: Not sure why I am getting down voted. This is a valid answer, not necessarily the most elegant

Answer (score 1):

Another solution loosely building on presented code:

```rb
def initials(name)
  name.scan(/([[:alpha:]])[[:alpha:]]*/).flatten.join.upcase
end
```

Use `[[:alpha:]]` (a ["POSIX bracket expression"](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes)) instead of the classic `\w` to match non-ASCII characters which do come up in names. The regex matches whole words but only captures first letters.

Answer (score -1):

```
def initials(name)
  (name.split.drop(1).map do |subname|
    subname[0].upcase
  end + [name.split.last]).join('.')
end

initials("Bob Smith Jones")
```